# Consulta para mostrar datos de un solo usuario de tablas de MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, web

Necesito mostrar en mi página el contenido de una tabla según el usuario que haya iniciado sesión. Estoy incluyendo la conexión y las consultas donde debo acceder para mostrarme los datos del usuario, que ya están cargados en los campos de las tablas de la base de datos.

¿Estoy haciendo bien las consultas y las tablas para que sean mostradas en mi página?

```
<?php
session_start();
include "../conexion.php";
include "conexion.php";
$re=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_alumno 
                WHERE CURP='".$_POST['Usuario']."' 
                AND CONTRASENA='".$_POST['Password']."'") or die(mysql_error());
if(isset($arreglo)){
  $_SESSION['Usuario']=$arreglo;
  header("Location: ../admin.php");
}else{
  header("Location: ../login.php?error=datos no validos");
}

$re=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM basico 
                  WHERE CURP ='".$_POST['NOMBRE']."' 
                  AND APELLIDO_PATERNO='".$_POST['APELLIDO_MATERNO']."' ")  
$re2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM basico WHERE CURP ");
$basico=0;
echo '<table border="0px" width="100%">';
while ($f=mysql_fetch_array($re)) {
  if($basico  !=$f['basico']){
      echo '<tr><td>CURP: '.$f['basico'].' </td></tr>';
  }
  $basico=$f['basico'];
  echo '<tr>
          <td>'.$f['CURP'].'</td>
          <td>'.$f['NOMBRE'].'</td>
          <td>'.$f['APELLIDO_PATERNO'].'</td>
          <td>'.$f['APELLIDO_MATERNO'].'</td>
        </tr>';
}
echo '</table>';

$re=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM boleta WHERE CURP='".$_POST['Usuario']."'");
if(isset($arreglo)){
  $_SESSION['Usuario']=$arreglo;
  header("Location: ../admin.php");
}else{
  header("Location: ../login.php?error=datos no validos");
}

$re=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM boleta WHERE CURP'".$_POST['CURP']."' 
    AND   CALIFICACION1='".$_POST['CALIFICACION1']."' 
    AND CALIICACION2='".$_POST['CALIFICACION2']."' 
    AND CALIICACION3='".$_POST['CALIFICACION3']."' 
    AND CALIFICACION_FINAL='".$_POST['CALIFICACIONF']."' 
    AND ASISENCIA1='".$_POST['ASISTENCIA1']."' 
    AND CALIICACION2='".$_POST['CALIFICACION2']."' 
    AND ASISTENCIA3='".$_POST['ASISTENCIA3']."'");
//Falta la condicion del campo de BB.DD CURL
$re2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM basico WHERE CURP=... ");
$boleta=0;
echo '<table border="0px" width="100%">';
while ($f=mysql_fetch_array($re)) {
        if($basico  !=$f['basico']){
          echo '<tr><td>CURP: '.$f['basico'].' </td></tr>';
        }
        $basico=$f['basico'];
        echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$f['CURP'].'</td>
                <td>'.$f['CALIFICACION1'].'</td>
                <td>'.$f['CALIFICACION2'].'</td>
                <td>'.$f['CALIFICACION3'].'</td>
                <td>'.$f['CALIFICACIONF'].'</td>
                <td>'.$f['ASISTENCIA1'].'</td>
                <td>'.$f['ASISTENCIA2'].'</td>
                <td>'.$f['ASISTENCIA3'].'</td>
              </tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Te paso una revisión rápida de tu código, he corregido solo los fallos mas evidentes. Pero por ponerte un ejemplo, cuando haces las consultas a la BB.DD siempre se las asignas a la misma variable.

```
<?php
session_start();
include "../conexion.php";
include "conexion.php";
$re=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_alumno 
                WHERE CURP='".$_POST['Usuario']."' 
                AND CONTRASENA='".$_POST['Password']."'") or die(mysql_error());
if(isset($arreglo)){
$_SESSION['Usuario']=$arreglo;
  header("Location: ../admin.php");

}else{
    //DISTINTO NUMERO DE <td> LA TABLA SALDRA MAL FORMADA
  header("Locatio colspan="3"n: ../login.php?error=datos no validos");
}

$re=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM basico 
                  WHERE CURP ='".$_POST['NOMBRE']."' 
                  AND APELLIDO_PATERNO='".$_POST['APELLIDO_MATERNO']."' ");

$re2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM basico WHERE CURP ");
$basico=0;
echo '<table border="0px" width="100%">';
while ($f=mysql_fetch_array($re)) {
  if($basico  !=$f['basico']){
      //DISTINTO NUMERO DE <td> LA TABLA SALDRA MAL FORMADA
      echo '<tr><td colspan="3">CURP: '.$f['basico'].' </td></tr>';
  }
  $basico=$f['basico'];
  echo '<tr>
          <td>'.$f['CURP'].'</td>
          <td>'.$f['NOMBRE'].'</td>
          <td>'.$f['APELLIDO_PATERNO'].'</td>
          <td>'.$f['APELLIDO_MATERNO'].'</td>
        </tr>';
echo '</table>';

$re=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM boleta WHERE CURP='".$_POST['Usuario']."'");
if(isset($arreglo)){
  $_SESSION['Usuario']=$arreglo;
  header("Location: ../admin.php");
}else{
  header("Location: ../login.php?error=datos no validos");
}

$re=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM boleta WHERE CURP'".$_POST['CURP']."' 
    AND   CALIFICACION1='".$_POST['CALIFICACION1']."' 
    AND CALIICACION2='".$_POST['CALIFICACION2']."' 
    AND CALIICACION3='".$_POST['CALIFICACION3']."' 
    AND CALIFICACION_FINAL='".$_POST['CALIFICACIONF']."' 
    AND ASISENCIA1='".$_POST['ASISTENCIA1']."' 
    AND CALIICACION2='".$_POST['CALIFICACION2']."' 
    AND ASISTENCIA3='".$_POST['ASISTENCIA3']."')";

$re2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM basico WHERE CURP ");
$boleta=0;
echo '<table border="0px" width="100%">';
while ($f=mysql_fetch_array($re)) {
    if($basico  !=$f['basico']){
      echo '<tr><td>CURP: '.$f['basico'].' </td></tr>';
    }
    $basico=$f['basico'];
    echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$f['CURP'].'</td>
            <td>'.$f['CALIFICACION1'].'</td>
            <td>'.$f['CALIFICACION2'].'</td>
            <td>'.$f['CALIFICACION3'].'</td>
            <td>'.$f['CALIFICACIONF'].'</td>
            <td>'.$f['ASISTENCIA1'].'</td>
            <td>'.$f['ASISTENCIA2'].'</td>
            <td>'.$f['ASISTENCIA3'].'</td>
          </tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Tendrias que poner en la consulta un `WHERE id_usuario = id_usuario` (primer id_usuario es de la tabla "boleto" y el segundo id_usuario seria de la tabla de usuarios.